# Как автоматически включить службу удаленного рабочего стола

Tags: python

Нынешний код не включает службу удаленного рабочего стола
код:

```py
import subprocess

# включение удаленного рабочего стола
subprocess.call("reg add \"HKLM\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Terminal Server\" /v fDenyTSConnections /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f", shell=True)

# перезапуск службы удаленного рабочего стола
subprocess.call("net stop TermService", shell=True)
subprocess.call("net start TermService", shell=True)
```

как можно это исправить? может быть нужно использовать другую библиотеку?